# Is it possible to run a job either automatically or manual depending on variable gitlab?

Tags: gitlab

We have the need to sometimes when triggering a pipeline run to run all of the jobs manually and in other cases we need to run all the jobs automatically when the same pipeline is triggered.

The ideal implementation would have the pipeline run either automatically or manual based on a custom variable, let's say `RUN_AUTOMATICALLY` like

```
#.gitlab-ci.yml wanted example
test-build:
  script:
    - echo "this is just an example"
  when: 
   - if(RUN_AUTOMATICALLY == true) {on_success } else {manual}
```

However the [`when` keyword](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#when) does not seem to support expressions or working with variables.

Is there any way to either run the steps in a pipeline manual or automatically in a programmatic manner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking more into this and thinking it is not possible, I've managed to implement choosing between automatic or manual run type using the `rules` keyword combined with `when` as per:

```
  test-build:
    script:
    - echo "this is a working example"
    rules:
    - if: '$RUN_AUTOMATICALLY == "true"'
       when: on_success
    # any other case
    - when: manual
```